# How to get the sum in a joined table when using group by - getting wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have two tables `orders` and `order_items`. I need to group the results by days. But I also need to get the sum of `energy_used` for each day from another table. When I try that using a join, I get wrong `order_sum` for each day. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am using joins because I would also like to sort by these columns later.

Here is my `orders` table

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | order_sum | user_id | created_at          |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 25.13     | 7       | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 14.00     | 5       | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 3  | 35.00     | 1       | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

And here is my `order_items` table

```
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | energy_used | created_at          |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 65          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 1        | 12          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 3  | 2        | 70          | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 4  | 2        | 5           | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 5  | 3        | 0           | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

And this is the desired result that I am trying to achieve

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| date_of_month | total_order_sum | total_energy_used | last_order_date     | last_order_sum |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2020-01-25    | 25.13           | 77                | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 | 25.13          |
| 2020-01-26    | 14.00           | 75                | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 | 14.00          |
| 2020-01-27    | 35.00           | 0                 | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 | 35.00          |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

And here is my query that I have tried but I'm getting wrong results, the order_sum is not being calculated correctly because of my join with the order_items table

```
SELECT
    DATE(orders.created_at) AS date_of_month,
    SUM(orders.order_sum) AS order_sum,
    order_items.energy_used
FROM
    orders
JOIN (
    select
        order_id,
        sum(energy_used) as energy_used
    from
        order_items
    group by
        date(created_at)
) as order_items on order_items.order_id = orders.id
JOIN (
    select
        max(created_at) as last_order_date,
        max(order_sum) as last_order_sum
    from
        orders
    order by created at desc
    limit 1
) as orders2 on orders2.id = orders.id
GROUP BY
    date_of_month
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB I am using version 5.5

Comment: A good 'rule-of-thumb' is that if an non-aggregated column appears in the SELECT, then it MUST also appear in the GROUP BY.

Comment: What is the logic for `last_order_sum`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff last_order_sum is to take the sum(order_sum) of max(created_at) from the orders table

Comment: @Liga . . . It has decimal points.  None of the values in the sample data have decimal parts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the order_sum is in decimal type and so the last order will be also

Comment: Your query cannot possibly run; the subquery orders2 does not select the ID column demanded by the join predicate

Comment: @GordonLinoff for the last_order_sum it would be ````select order_sum from orders order by created_at desc limit 1````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want, for each day:

- the sum of `order_items.energy_used` for all orders created that day
- the `created_at` and `order_sum` that correspond to the latest `order` created on that day

Your sample data is not very representative of that - it has only one order per day. Also it is unclear why `created_at` is repeated in both tables; you should really be relying on the `order_id` to relate both tables

Here is a query for the above purpose: this works by joining the `orders` table with an aggregate query that computes the total energy per day (using `order_id` to get the `created_at` date from `orders`), and filters on the latest order per day:

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    i.total_energy_used,
    o.created_at last_order_date,
    o.order_sum last_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select date(o1.created_at) date_of_month, sum(i1.energy_used) total_energy_used
    from orders o1
    inner join order_items i1 on o1.id = i1.order_id
    group by date(o1.created_at)
) i on i.date_of_month = date(o.created_at)
where o.created_at = (
    select max(o1.created_at)
    from orders o1
    where date(o1.created_at) = date(o.created_at)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b4d5c17b0604385692ba34bca94cbe7f)**:

```
date_of_month | total_energy_used | last_order_date     | last_order_sum
:------------ | ----------------: | :------------------ | -------------:
2020-01-25    |                77 | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |          25.13
2020-01-26    |                75 | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |          14.00
2020-01-27    |                 0 | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |          35.00
```

Comment: only missing order_sum for each day because one day can have many orders

Comment: @Liga: this is unclear to me. Is `last_order_sum` the `order_sum` of the *last* order per day, or the sum of all `order_sum`s on that day? As I said, your sample data has only one order per day, so I had to make assumptions, which are detailed in my answer.

Comment: ````last_order_sum```` is the order_sum of the last order per day - correct. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I also wanted to get the ````order_sum```` for each day.. (so there can be many orders in one day, so to get the total order_sum per each day). updated the question.

Comment: ok thanks, I will do that. I somehow left out that one little detail...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to separate out the energy for the last day in the month.  If so:

```
SELECT DATE(o.created_at) AS date_of_month,
       SUM(oi.energy_used) AS order_sum,
       MAX(o.created_at) as last_order_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.max_ca = o.created_at THEN oi.energy_used END) as max_energy_used
FROM orders o JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON oi.order_id = o.id JOIN
     (SELECT DATE(o.created_at) as date_ca, MAX(o.created_at) as max_ca
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY DATE(o.created_at)
     ) d
     ON DATE(o.created_at) = d.date_ca
GROUP BY date_of_month
```

Comment: Umm, I wanted to get total energy used for each day for the orders of each day

Comment: @Liga . . . This query does that.

Comment: Oh I see, I am getting the wrong ````energy_used```` I am not getting the sum of all energy used for each day..