# Getting wrong sum when using group by with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

With reference to this question ([How to get the sum in a joined table when using group by - getting wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932321/how-to-get-the-sum-in-a-joined-table-when-using-group-by-getting-wrong-results)) I have two tables `orders` and `order_items`. I need to group the results by days. But I also need to get the sum of `energy_used` for each day from another table. When I try that using a join, I get wrong `order_sum` for each day (they are not being summed up). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would like to get for each day

- the sum of `order_items.energy_used` for all orders created that day
- the sum of `orders.order_sum` for all orders created that day
- the `created_at` and `order_sum` that correspond to the latest `order` created on that day

Here is my `orders` table

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | order_sum | user_id | created_at          |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 25.13     | 7       | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 10.00     | 7       | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 |
| 3  | 14.00     | 5       | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 4  | 35.00     | 1       | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

And here is my `order_items` table

```
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | energy_used | created_at          |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 65          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 1        | 12          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 3  | 2        | 70          | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 4  | 2        | 5           | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 5  | 3        | 0           | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

And this is the desired result that I am trying to achieve

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| date_of_month | total_order_sum | total_energy_used | last_order_date     | last_order_sum |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2020-01-25    | 35.13           | 77                | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 | 25.13          |
| 2020-01-26    | 14.00           | 75                | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 | 14.00          |
| 2020-01-27    | 35.00           | 0                 | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 | 35.00          |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

And here is the query that I have tried but I'm getting wrong results, the order_sum is not being calculated correctly. It is showing the same as `last_order_sum`

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    i.total_energy_used,
    o.created_at last_order_date,
    o.order_sum last_order_sum,
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select date(o1.created_at) date_of_month, sum(i1.energy_used) total_energy_used
    from orders o1
    inner join order_items i1 on o1.id = i1.order_id
    group by date(o1.created_at)
) i on i.date_of_month = date(o.created_at)
where o.created_at = (
    select max(o1.created_at)
    from orders o1
    where date(o1.created_at) = date(o.created_at)
)
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=92b8cc2920ad9f7a7cdd56bded5a3bf2

Comment: So, `created_at` is considered the order date? And that goes for both `orders.created_at` and `order_items.created_at`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes that is correct

Comment: If you want to group, why do you not use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? (Getting the last_order_sum may be a bit tricky, and easier solved with MySQL 8 than in previous versions.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using 5.5

Comment: Your example suggests that there can be orders without order_items (`2020-01-25 15:23:00`). Is this really the case? And shouldn't it be `last_order_date` / `last_order_sum` = `2020-01-25 15:23:00` / `10.00` rather than `2020-01-25 09:13:00` / `25.13` for `2020-01-25`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner well for each day there would be a last order date and sum. There shouldn't be orders without order_items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always join tables together on their relationships (in this case orders.id with order_items.order_id) and then group. to avoid duplicating order_sums for multiple order_items when joining, first group order_items by order_id.

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    sum(i.total_energy_used),
    max(o.created_at),
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, sum(total_energy_used) total_energy_used
    from order_items i
    group by order_id
) i on o.id = i.order_id
group by date(o.created_at)
```

from this point onwards you can do a join again on orders with max(o.created_at) to get the order_sum of the last order.
moral of the story: keep an eye on your granularity.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was looking for. Just need to figure out that last join to get the order_sum

Comment: So far, no luck, I tried to use order by created_at and limit one but can't get the last order_sum

Comment: this whole thing will be a subquery (say X)
then you have select * from X left join orders o on max_created_at = o.created_at. again watch out for duplication, is a created_at always unique in orders?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are selecting from `orders`, where you actually want an aggregate of `orders` by date. So select from two aggregtating subqueries that you join. Only problem is `last_order_sum`, which we can select in a further subquery, once we know the last order date.

```
select 
  order_date,
  o.total_order_sum,
  oi.total_energy_used,
  o.last_order_date,
  (
    select order_sum
    from orders last_order
    where lastorder.created_at = o.last_order_date
  ) as last_order_sum
from 
(
  select
    date(created_at) as order_date,
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum,
    max(created_date) as last_order_date
  from orders
  group by date(created_at)
) o
inner join 
(
  select
    date(created_at) as order_date,
    sum(energy_used) as total_energy_used
  from order_items
  group by date(created_at)
) oi using(order_date)
order by order_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking and what you show us in output are not correlated. Assuming that it is a typo:

```
select so.dtDay as date_of_month, so.order_sum as total_order_sum,
   eu.energy_used as total_energy_used,
   o.created_at as last_order_date,
   o.order_sum as last_order_sum
from (
select left(created_at,10) as dtDay, sum(order_sum) as order_sum, max(id) as last_insert_id
from orders
group by left(created_at,10)
order by created_at
) so
inner join orders o on o.id = so.last_insert_id
left join (select left(created_at,10) as dtDay, sum(energy_used) as energy_used
from order_items
group by left(created_at,10)) eu on so.dtDay = eu.dtDay;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2dc06940815eaf108659c54f8355f7e9)