# Can't get the last order sum for each day when using group by and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables `orders` and `order_items`. I need to group the results by days.

But I also need to get for each day:

- 1) the sum of `order_items.energy_used` for all orders created that day
- 2) the sum of `orders.order_sum` for all orders created that day
- 3) the last `created_at` and `order_sum` that correspond to the latest order created on that day

I am able to get everything except the last sum of `order_sum` for each day.

Here is my `orders` table

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | order_sum | user_id | created_at          |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 25.13     | 7       | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 10.00     | 7       | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 |
| 3  | 14.00     | 5       | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 4  | 50.00     | 5       | 2020-01-26 19:14:00 |
| 5  | 35.00     | 1       | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

And here is my `order_items` table

```
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | energy_used | created_at          |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1        | 65          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 2  | 1        | 12          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 3  | 1        | 12          | 2020-01-25 09:13:00 |
| 4  | 2        | 70          | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 |
| 5  | 2        | 5           | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 |
| 6  | 3        | 0           | 2020-01-26 10:14:00 |
| 7  | 4        | 1           | 2020-01-26 19:14:00 |
| 8  | 5        | 5           | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 |
+----+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

And this is the desired result that I am trying to achieve

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| date_of_month | total_order_sum | total_energy_used | last_order_date     | last_order_sum |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 2020-01-25    | 35.13           | 164               | 2020-01-25 15:23:00 | 10.00          |
| 2020-01-26    | 64.00           | 1                 | 2020-01-26 19:14:00 | 50.00          |
| 2020-01-27    | 35.00           | 5                 | 2020-01-27 11:13:00 | 35.00          |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    sum(i.total_energy_used),
    max(o.created_at),
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
    from order_items i
    group by order_id
) i on o.id = i.order_id
group by date(o.created_at)
```

I tried adding another join like this but it didn't work

```
inner join (
    select
        date(created_at) as date_of_month,
        order_sum as last_order_sum
    from
        orders
    where
        created_at = (select max(created_at) from orders)
) as orders2 on orders2.date_of_month = orders.date_of_month
```

Comment: for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933093/getting-wrong-sum-when-using-group-by-with-inner-join

Comment: I would expect your first query to return total_order_sum - does it return nothing or does it return the wrong value?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes but I am not getting the last order_sum for each day, any ideas?

Comment: Can we close this question now?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, this is solved now, thank you for all the help!

Comment: Consider accepting an answer below, or adding your own answer and accepting that, or deleting the question

Comment: I added P.Salmon's answer that solved the issue. But I can only accept my own answer in 2 days it says.

Answer (score 1):

try like below no need subquery and use created_at in join

```
 select b.*,total_energy_used from 
(select a.*,o1.order_sum as last_order_sum from  (select date(created_at) as day,
sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum,
max(created_at) as last_order_date

from orders o group by day
) a join orders o1 on a.last_order_date = o1.created_at
) b
join 
(
select date(created_at) as d, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
from order_items i
group by date(created_at)
) c on c.d=b.day
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'o.created_at=i.created_at group by date(o.created_at)

Comment: @Liga there was typo i missed on  check now

Comment: Not getting any results returned. If you look at the desired table I posted you can see the fields I am looking for

Comment: @Liga there was another change in join datetime need to convert in date i have edited

Comment: This returns total sum of energy used but not for each day. It is in the other table. Also it didn't return the last order sum. If you look at the desired results table you can see those fields there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206770/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-liga).

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT                      
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    SUM(i.total_energy_used),
    MAX(o.created_at),     
    solangi.order_sum as total_order_sum

FROM orders o              

LEFT OUTER JOIN (          

SELECT iii.*  FROM order_items AS iii WHERE iii.id = (SELECT ii.id FROM order_items ii WHERE ii.i.created_at= (SELECT MAX(i.created_at) FROM order_items i  GROUP BY  DATE( i.created_at  ) ORDER BY i.created_at  DESC))

) solangi ON solangi.id = o.id


GROUP BY DATE(o.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to P.Salmon for all the help, this has been solved with this query

```
select 
    date(o.created_at) date_of_month,
    sum(order_sum) as total_order_sum,
    sum(i.total_energy_used) total_energy_used,
    max(o.created_at) lastorderdate,
    max(s.last_order_sum) last_order_sum
from orders o
inner join (
    select order_id, sum(energy_used) total_energy_used
    from order_items i
    group by order_id
) i on o.id = i.order_id
join
(select order_sum last_order_sum,created_at
    from orders o
    where created_at = (select max(created_at) from orders o1 where date(o1.created_at) = date(o.created_at))
) s on date(s.created_at) = date(o.created_at) 
group by date(o.created_at);
```